# How to override handlers in mapbox-gl-js?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

Mapbox-gl-js has "Handlers" - https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#Handlers

How would one override a handler, for example the ScrollZoomHandler?

I would like to override the ScrollZoomHandler _onWheel method in order to adjust the mouse position to compensate for a CSS transformed map container.

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/d6c34c81f7b0d6e77f1b25c2c080a3c5afba94ab/js/ui/handler/scroll_zoom.js

Answer (score 0):

If you need custom interaction handling, I recommend disabling the handler and writing your own interaction handling code outside of GL JS.

```
mapbox.scrollZoom.disable();

addEventListener('wheel', document.getElementById('map'), function() {
    ...
    map.zoomTo(...)
    ...
}, false);
```